# Encrypted Xubuntu boots right into initramfs after install, not asking for password

Tags: boot, encryption

I made a fresh **Xubuntu 22.04.2 LTS** installation on my machine using a LUKS encrypted root partition.
I created following partitions:

- efi: 512MB EFI partition (unencrypted)
- boot: 1024MB ext4 partition (unencrypted)
- root: 126.5GB LUKS encrypted ext4 partition

On a different disk, I have my /home folder. They're all always present.

I setup Xubuntu to mount as follows:

- nvme0n1p1: efi (EFI)
- nvme0n1p2: boot (/boot)
- nvme0n1p3: root (/)
- sda1: home (/home)

Setup installs successfully, however after rebooting my machine, the boot screen shows up and after a couple of seconds I get right into **initramfs** with following error message:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
[...]
ALERT! UUID=1234abcd... does not exist! [...]
```

I am not even asked for my encryption password.

Is that a common issue or did I miss something?
The partition with given UUID does exist as my (decrypted) root partition.

Comment: You've provided no release details (*thus we'd have to guess somewhat as to your exact install as minor changes occur between releases*), though I suspect your issue may relate to the multiple drives & uEFI settings that exist & install (*and if one drive is removed or both are always present wasn't defined*)

Comment: @guiverc sorry, you're right, I've edited my question.